# What does "+=" mean?

Tags: c++

I'm working with an esp8266 and want to have it default to an access point when it cannot connect to a wifi network.  I'm using chriscook8's example from github [here](https://github.com/chriscook8/esp-arduino-apboot/blob/master/ESP-wifiboot.ino).

chriscook8 uses "+=" in several places and I can't find an explanation of what that means.

Here is an example from setup():

```
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  EEPROM.begin(512);
  delay(10);
  Serial.println();
  Serial.println();
  Serial.println("Startup");
  // read eeprom for ssid and pass
  Serial.println("Reading EEPROM ssid");
  String esid;
  for (int i = 0; i < 32; ++i)
  {
    esid += char(EEPROM.read(i));  //<- here
  }
```

What does += do?

Comment: This belongs on stackoverflow.com, not here. Stackoverflow is the site for programming questions, as this asks about C++'s syntax.

Comment: Google for [C++ operators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C%2B%2B)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It adds the value or variable on the right to the variable on the left and assigns the result to the variable on the left.

```
A += B
```

is the same as:

```
A = A + B
```

It's short-hand.

In the case of a String it concatenates the right hand item on to the end of the left hand item.

Comment: Thank you.  Is it considered better form to use +=?

Comment: It makes no real difference. It's just quicker to type. Also it's a historical thing - when storage space was at a premium saving bytes here and there could make a difference. I recall at University I had a maximum storage space of 4MB for *all* my work on the servers. Saving space like that was good.

Comment: I'm not sure it's correct to say that it "assigns the result to the *value* on the left. A "value" is the result of evaluation; you cannot assign anything to a value. The right word would be variable, or maybe location.

Comment: The computer will not function differently with `A += 1` or `A = A + 1`, but the code is simply easier to read.  If your variables are more descriptive, say `AmountOfDaysWorked`, then `AmountOfDaysWorked += 1` is easier to read than `AmountOfDaysWorked = AmountOfDaysWorked + 1`.  It gets worse if you have to add a variable to another variable.

Comment: @Sahuagin: You're right that *value* is not precisely correct. But neither is *variable*: I can assign to `str->field`, but this is not a variable; it is a (compound) expression. The term you are looking for is *lvalue* ("ell-value"), which is merely "something that can appear on the left-hand side of an assignment expression." (Circular? Perhaps. But that is the term.)

Comment: @wchargin I forgot about the word "lvalue". Its name suggests that I may have been wrong to say that "value" was incorrect, though I think "value" alone generally means "rvalue". "Variable" is correct in this specific case, though isn't the broadest possible term.

Comment: @sahuagin agreed!

Answer (score 3):

`+=` is a common programming shortcut. An example: (pseudo-code)

```
num1 = 7
num2 = 15
#these two lines are exactly the same
num1 += num2
num1 = num1 + num2
```

`+=` is extremely useful for increasing the value of a variable by another variable. It also works similarly with `-=`, `*=`, and `/=`

Comment: The assignment versions of binary operators include the arithmetic, bitwise logical, and shift operators: *=, /=, %=, +=, -=, <<=, >>=, &=, ^=, and |=. Expr1 <opr>= Expr2 is equivalent to Expr1 = Expr1 <opr> Expr2, except that Expr1 will only be evaluated once (important if Expr1 has side effects).

Answer (score 0):

In the earliest days of the C language (I'm talking late 60's here), the compilers did not do much (if any) optimization, and a lot of the constructs in C were put in so that a programmer could get a more optimized program by using hints like +=.  So, in those days, `A = A + 5` generated three PDP11 instructions, while `A += 5` was only a single PDP11 instruction.  That meant that most programmers learned to write it that way.  But because it was more concise and to many also more readable, the C constructs with `<op>=` have made it into most modern languages.

Comment: But as other comments have said, general programming questions have their own StackExchange sites...actually several of them...